# How to add first row to the csv_read values?

Tags: python, csv

I read sorted csv files from a folder and append the values in a matrix but first value is missing (because it is consider as header or 'series' by read_csv. How can I add series values to my matrix?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import numpy as np

import re
def sorted_aphanumeric(data):
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    return sorted(data, key=alphanum_key)


Path = '/home/'
raw_data = []
dirlist = sorted_aphanumeric(os.listdir(Path))
count = 0

for files in dirlist:
    a = str(files)
    if a.endswith('.csv'):
        count = count + 1
        QS_path = Path + files
        reader = pd.read_csv(QS_path)
        raw_data.append(reader.values)
```

Comment: [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) is not the best option to check if str can be converted to `int()`, better to use [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) instead. Check docs of both functions and find the difference ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader = pd.read_csv(QS_path, header=None)
```